# Check for VMX Unrestricted Guest IA-32e required by VMware Workstation 14?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

Is there a way, without installing vmware, to check from within Linux for the presence of "**VMX Unrestricted Guest**" support which is a requirement for VMware Workstation 14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unrestricted guest support is indicated by bit 5 of MSR 0x485, so it can be checked as follows:

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo rdmsr --bitfield 5:5 0x485
```

If the output is 1, unrestricted guest is supported, if it’s 0, it’s not.

`rdmsr` is available in the `msr-tools` package in Debian or Fedora.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone on Arch - `msr-tools` is in the AUR.